# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. this было 0x1EA5EC35E20

Tags: c++, объекты, visual-studio-code, деструктор

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня проблема с пониманием удаления объекта класса из динамической памяти. У меня есть простой класс Student:

```
class Student {
private:
    string lessons[2] = {string("lesson1"), string("lesson2")};

public:
    Student() {
    
    }

    ~Student() {
        delete lessons;
    }
    void showInfo() {
    cout << "Элективы: ";
        int size = sizeof(lessons) / sizeof(string);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << lessons[i] << "\t";
        }
   } 
};
```

Код в main():

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    Student *student = new Student("Salavat", "МГУ ВМК", 22, 1);

    student->showInfo();
 
    delete student;   // после этой строчки выводится исключение 

    return 0;
}
```

Текст исключения:
Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
this было 0x1EA5EC35E20.

Текст из отладчика :

```
 "cpp_tutorial.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll". 
 "cpp_tutorial.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll". 
 "cpp_tutorial.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll". 
 Поток 0x4868 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
 Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
 **this** было 0x1EA5EC35E20.
```

Значения переменных при дебаггинге:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Буду благодарен, если объясните, почему выходит ошибка при попытке напрямую удалить объект student.**

**(delete student;)**

Comment: Думаю проблема в том, что в деструкторе вы пытаетесь вызвать оператор delete на переменную-член, которая не была выделена отдельно от класса в динамической памяти. Уберите delete из деструктора и все будет работать

Comment: Это связано с тем, что при применении к классу delete память освобождается, занятая всем классом. Ваша переменная-член - это кусок памяти этого класса. И она также освобождается при вызове delete В main. Еще один delete в деструкторе не нужен. А вот если бы это был указатель, а в конструкторе вы бы инициализировали указатель оператором `new`, то нужно было бы в деструкторе дополнительно указывать delete для указателя

Comment: Когда вы вызываете delete в main, вызывается деструктор класса. При уничтожении класса вызываются автоматически деструкторы переменных-членов класса. Если это обычная переменная, как у вас, то она уничтожается сама. Если же это указатель, то вызывается "деструктор" указателя, но память, на которую указывает указатель (извините за тавтологию) не освобождается. Поэтому в случае с указателем нужен delete в деструкторе, чтобы запустить процесс освобождения памяти, выделенной при помощи new уже внутри класса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уничтожайте с помощью `delete` то, что не было выделено с помощью `new`.

Для `string lessons[2]` память не выделялась с помощью `new`, а удалять в деструкторе вы ее пытаетесь — вот и получаете неприятности. Вот если бы она была выделена как

```
string * lessons;
...
Student():lessons(new string[2]) {}
```

то дело другое... Кстати, тогда ее надо было бы и освобождать не `delete lessons;`,
а `delete[] lessons;`.